# Qt Creator Unit Test Project

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qt-creator, qtestlib

In Qt Creator, when I create a new Unit Test project it will not build successfully if the full path to the project contains a space.

I've tracked the bug down to the makefile produced by qmake.  The makefile contains a line near the top like:

```
DEFINES = -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DSRCDIR=\"C:/Users/Smith/Qt Projects/Unit_Tests/\" -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_TESTLIB_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR=\"C:/Users/Smith/Qt Projects/Debug_Unit_Tests\"
```

The quotes in the values for `SRCDIR` and `QT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR` are escaped with backslashes.  If I delete the backslashes from `Makefile.Debug`, then the project will build successfully.

Obviously, I don't want to have manually delete the backslashes every time.  I'd also like to avoid a custom build step that removes the backslashes.  Because qmake has so many options, I was hoping there was something I could just put in the `.pro` file that will fix this.

I tried something like `DEFINES -= QT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR`.  That doesn't work however because `QT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR` is not yet defined.  `testlib` apparently adds its own definitions later.

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2010 SP 1
- Qt 5.0.2
- Qt Creator 2.7.0
- Windows 7

What's the simplest way to get rid of the backslashes?

**Edit:** This also happens OSX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definitions added by `testlib` are in `testlib_defines.prf` which is in:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010\mkspecs\features
```

Change...

```
DEFINES += QT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR=\\\"$$OUT_PWD\\\"
```

...to...

```
DEFINES += QT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR=\"$$OUT_PWD\"
```

The other part is easy.  The extra backslashes for `SRCDIR` come from the `.pro` file itself.  Change...

```
DEFINES += SRCDIR=\\\"$$PWD/\\\"
```

...to...

```
DEFINES += SRCDIR=\"$$PWD/\"
```

Every time you install a new version of Qt, you'll have to edit the `.prf` file but that's better than having to edit the makefile every time qmake runs.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but once you've changed the .prf file, you'll have to explicitly run qmake again for QtCreator to see the updated QT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR.